# HP Laptop : Not even a single function key is working Hp wired keyboard in ubuntu 17.04

Tags: keyboard, hp, 17.04

I'm using Ubuntu 17.04 which is installed on HP laptop. Currently I'm using external keyboard and not even a single function key is working from the external keyboard. Do i need to remap the function keys from the external keyboard to the Ubuntu ? Although I checked whether my keyboard is alright or not. So i used `xev` for this purpose and `xev` is responding to all the events generated by these keys. Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Some keyboards have Fn key and function keys only work if you press Fn too. If you press function keys without Fn, the other functionalities are used like screen brightness, volume, etc. Some keyboards even have Fn Lock.

Comment: No my keyboard doesn't have the fn key that means function key must work without fn key. Please help me. @nobody